# K-means for data sets with scalar and vector objects

Tags: clustering, k-means, cosine-similarity

My question consists of two parts, both possibly closely related:

**Part 1:**

I have a dataset where the incoming data ($x$) will be an eigenvector ($V$) and an associated eigenvalue ($\lambda$). That is:

$x_i=[V_i,\lambda_i] = [{v_i}_1,{v_i}_2,{v_i}_3,...,{v_i}_d,\lambda_i]$, where $V_i\in \mathbb{R}^d, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$, and so $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.

I am therefore trying to cluster data which is the combination of a vector and a scalar. My question is when I apply k-means, or any other sort of clustering algorithm on this dataset I will require the use of a similarity metric.

Should the similarity metric be calculated/interpreted like:

$sim(x_i,x_{i+1})=\sqrt{||V_i-V_{i+1}||^2 + |\lambda_i-\lambda_{i+1}|^2}$

That is, basically calculated 'feature-wise' (one feature being the eigenvector, the other feature being the eigenvalue). Or should similarity metrics be calculated/interpreted as follows:

$sim(x_i,x_{i+1})=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{k=d}|{v_i}_k-{v_{i+1}}_k|^2+ |\lambda_i-\lambda_{i+1}|^2} $

In the latter case, the eigenvector is seen in its individual components (that is, just a bunch of norms on scalar objects ... almost indistinguishable from the eigenvalue norm - another norm on scalars), whereas in the first appraoch I consider the eigenvector as the entire feature object. Mathematically the two approaches are the same, but as far as correct interpretation goes, which is more correct? Would you say that the advantage to the first approach is that then I open to door to more similarity metrics? Such as instead of having to use $||V_i-V_{i+1}||^2$, I could use $V_i\cdot V_{i+1}$? If I use this dot product metric is it still k-means? (since k-means is defined using the L2 norm).

**Part 2:**

For this particular problem it seems like the presence of the eigenvector has the potential to 'over-power' the eigenvalue, especially if a norm like the L2 is used. That is for large $d$, $\sum_{k=1}^{k=d}|{v_i}_k-{v_{i+1}}_k|^2 >> |\lambda_i-\lambda_{i+1}|^2$.

Is there any good way around this? Is it possible to weight importance for the feature in clustering algorithms (i.e. have the eigenvalue seem to be just as important as the eigenvector for large $d$).

Thanks!

Comment: You can't put other distances into k-means easily. Use HAC for other measures, it is much more versatile! K-means is just for least-squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part 1, as you mentioned, both options you gave are equivalent, so neither is more correct (semantic sidepoint: you're actually talking about *distance* metrics, not similarity metrics). Actually, I don't think your proposed distance would be a good fit for this problem because eigenvectors are only specified up to sign flips. This means that $v$ and $-v$ should be considered identical. But, they would be considered distant using the $\ell_2$ distance as you proposed.

Regarding part 2: Yes, it's possible to use distance metrics where each dimension is weighted differently.

Offhand, it's hard to say which distance metric you *should* use. More information about the problem would be needed. Keep in mind that standard k-means is defined using squared Euclidean distances, so you would need to modify it to use something else. In particular, centroids must be computed differently (you can't just take the average of within-cluster points anymore).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer it helps my understanding immensely. If possible could I follow up on a few last things:

1. To fix your proposed "sign-flip" issue would the absolute values of the vectors be enough?
2. When I proposed the dot product between the eig-vectors is that still OK to use? Would this still be considered k-means?
3. Could you please link me the resources / sources where each dimension of a distance metric is weighted differently? Are these still used in the k-means clustering algorithm? 

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: 1. No, because $v$ and $|v|$ would be treated identically, when they may be different. 2. The dot product is related to cosine distance, which can be used for k-means. But, it would suffer from the same sign flip issue. You can probably modify cosine distance or the related angular distance to work for your purposes. As above, it's hard to say more without more detail about your problem. 3. Weighted Euclidean distance is a common example (but would also have sign flip issue).

Comment: Also just on your original reply you mention that "the centroids must be computed differently [for my problem]". I can't seem to think what is wrong with just taking the averages of my vectors, since they are just $d+1$ dimensional vectors of real numbers. Could you clarify your point there?

Comment: When solving the k-means optimization problem, the centroids are updated in a way that reduces the cost function. The cost function is typically the sum of squared L2 distances from points to their nearest centroids. In this case, centroids can be computed as averages because the average of a set of points is the point with minimum sum of squared L2 distances to points in the set. If you're using a different distance metric, a different procedure would be needed.

Comment: Your discussion has helped with my understanding a lot. I'll go over everything again an reflect. Thank you :). I'll mark this question as resolved.